# Passing component props to MDX Provider - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, markdown, react-props

Im using MDX Provider as shown below :-

```
      <MDXProvider components={components}>
        <ButtonMarkdown />
      </MDXProvider>
```

Components is :-

```
import { Button, Heading } from './components/button';

const components = {
  pre: (props: any) => <div {...props} />,
  h1: Heading,
  h2: Heading,
  h3: Heading,
  code: Codeblock,
  inlineCode: Codeblock,
};
```

However I want to be able to pass props into the Heading component being used in my markdown file eg :-

```
## Heading Two
```

should be changed to :-

```
<Heading level="2">Heading Two</Heading>
```

How would i do this to be able to ensure my markdown is being passed to correct props for the relevant component?

Comment: I know you probably don't need the answer anymore, but this question comes up in search a lot so I thought it would be good to have an answer posted since I had the code handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide several levels of headings in the `MDXProvider`:

```
<MDXProvider components={{
  h1: Heading1,
  h2: Heading2,
  h3: Heading3,
  h4: Heading4,
  pre: Code,
  table: Table,
  th: TableHeading,
  tr: TableRow,
  td: TableCell,
  p: Paragraph
}}>
  {children}
</MDXProvider>
```

They could be defined like this:

```
const Heading1: FC = ({ children }) => (
  <Heading level={1}>{children}</Heading>
);

const Heading2: FC = ({ children }) => (
  <Heading level={2}>{children}</Heading>
);

const Heading3: FC = ({ children }) => (
  <Heading level={3}>{children}</Heading>
);

const Heading4: FC = ({ children }) => (
  <Heading level={4}>{children}</Heading>
);
```

By the time the MDX renders, the second-level heading `##` will end up being replaced by `<Heading level={2}>`.

Just to make this answer more complete, this is one way to achieve a proper Heading component that will render `<h1>` when level prop is 1 and so on:

```
export const Heading: FC = ({
  level = 1,
  children,
}) => {
  const HeadingElement = `h${level}`;
  return (
    <HeadingElement>
      {children}
    </HeadingElement>
  );
};
```